# Can a Swift Concurrency Task be stored in a queue and started later?

Tags: swift, task, swift-concurrency

I need to defer the execution of a task until I complete a high priority task, such as re-authenticating, then execute the original task from there. I'm trying to use Swift Concurrency's [Task](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task) object for this:

```
Task {
    await service.fetch(...)
}
```

I see that I can `cancel` the task, but I want to stop/start it later instead. I was thinking of storing it in a queue and flushing the queue out after the high priority task finishes. Could this be done with Swift Concurrency, or I'm hoping I don't have to wrap an [Operation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation) object with async/await or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

From the WWDC 2021 video "Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes" a task schedules code to execute in the future, but doesn't give you a lot of control over when that task will execute.  In particular, even though you can provide a priority for a task, there are situations where you may still have priority inversion in the order tasks execute.

Your best bet for the type of control you seem to want is using Grand Central Dispatch and have both high priority and low priority queues feeding into a serial dispatch queue and then you can put your task in the appropriate queue.

EDIT: I just saw a construct that's new to me (been a while since I was working with GCD daily).  It's called a Workloop (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/workloop) and sounds like it might be just the ticket without manually tying dispatch queues together.